# selected/deselected not being added to nodes on click for bubble overlay chart

Tags: dc.js

I have tried to emulate the bubble overlay example as much as possible but the classes selected/deselected are not being added to the nodes, though the filter is applying. Can anyone offer any insight into this?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible, since `fadeDeselectedArea` gets invoked directly from `_doRedraw` and I'm seeing the classes applied properly on both the [Canadian crime example](redrawGroup) and the [stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/). Try putting a breakpoint on [that function](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/bubble-mixin.js#L167-L181) to make sure it's getting hit?

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I honestly don't know what to tell you. I added in a debugger statement where stated and even in the _doRedraw function. I even explicitly called it from the console to see if it worked and it does not. I will let you know if I find a solution but I have no idea why it is not behaving correctly. So even when explicitly calling _doRedraw I don't seem to be hitting it.

Comment: Thanks Gordon turns out there was a typo in the parent class name and that of the one used in the .svg call. We used an abstracted configuration file for this so it is one of those things that is difficult to catch. Thanks for your help